# Error: Rank mismatch in array reference and Warning: Real array index

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

I have wrote 2 programs in Fortran each one used for doing some calculating for some parameters.
After I joined both of them, I got some errors. I couldn't realise the reasons of such errors due to my lack experience in Fortran.

Here are the errors;

```
    CC2=CUBEROOT(NN,wq)
                 1
Warning: Extension: REAL array index at (1)
growthrate_vs_Il2.f90:46.20:

    CC2=CUBEROOT(NN,wq)
                    1
Warning: Extension: REAL array index at (1)
growthrate_vs_Il2.f90:46.16:

    CC2=CUBEROOT(NN,wq)
                1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (2/1)
growthrate_vs_Il2.f90:48.27:

    call fsub(CC2,Delta0,b,z1,z2,z3)
                           1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'f1' at (1); passed COMPLEX(4) to COMPLEX(8)
```

The code:

```
program main
implicit none
integer::i,j
real*8,dimension(1000)::Il2,Il3,a0,omega,nominator,dominator,ff,lamda,kk,b,c,d
real*8,dimension(1000)::growth_rate,cb1,cb2   
real*8,dimension(1000)::Il,Delta0, Delta1,m,CC,CC2,BB,mm,NN,wq
real*8::sumo,sumo2,a
real*8,parameter::mass_ratio=0.00870
complex*8,dimension(1000)::z1,z2,z3,f1,f2,f3
real*8,dimension(1000)::cuberoot
      Il=0.0
      Il2=0.0
      sumo=0.0
      a=1.0
do i=1,1000

      Il(i)=sumo+0.1

      omega(i) = 2.359*Il(i)
      nominator=2-omega(i)
      dominator=1-omega(i)
      ff(i)=nominator(i)/dominator(i)
      lamda(i)=sqrt(ff(i))
      kk(i)=1/lamda(i)

      Il2(i)=sumo2+0.001
      a0(i) = 0.68*Il2(i)


      b(i)=-(2.0+omega(i))
      cb1(i)=2.0*omega(i)
      cb2(i)=2.0*kk(i)*a0(i)*mass_ratio
      c(i)=(1.0d0+cb1(i)-cb2(i))
      d(i)=-(omega(i)+cc2(i))
      sumo=Il(i)
      sumo2=Il2(i)
end do

      Delta0= (b**2)-(3*a*c)
      Delta1= (2*(b**3))-(9*a*b*c)+(27*(a**2)*d)
      m=(Delta0)**3
      BB=(Delta1)**2
      mm= BB-(4*m)
      CC=sqrt(mm)
      NN=(Delta1+CC)/2
      CC2=CUBEROOT(NN,wq)

call fsub(CC2,Delta0,b,z1,z2,z3)

      print*,'Delta0',Delta0,'Delta1',Delta1,'mm',mm,'CC2',CC2

      print *, "Omega1_square= ",z1
      print *, "Omega2_square= ",z2
      print *, "Omega3_square= ",z3

end program
```

the subroutine and functions are as following:

```
subroutine fsub(x,t,s,f1,f2,f3)
implicit none
integer::k
real(kind=8), intent(in),dimension(1000) :: x,t,s
complex(kind=8), intent(out),dimension(1000) :: f1,f2,f3
complex(kind=8),dimension(1000)::z1,z2,z3

    z1=(1,0)
       f1=(-1/3)*(s+(z1*x)+(t/(z1*x)))
    z2=(-0.5,0.866)
       f2=(-1/3)*(s+(z2*x)+(t/(z2*x)))
    z3=(-0.5,-0.866)
       f3=(-1/3)*(s+(z3*x)+(t/(z3*x)))
end subroutine fsub

real (kind=8)   FUNCTION CUBEROOT (XX,cube_root)

  IMPLICIT NONE

  real(kind=8), INTENT(IN),dimension(1000) :: XX
  Real*8,dimension(1000):: log_x
  real(kind=8),Intent(out),dimension(1000) :: cube_root

       log_x=LOG(XX)
       cube_root=EXP(log_x/3.0)

  RETURN
END FUNCTION CUBEROOT
```

Comment: A few points: 1. use tag [tag:fortran], Fortran 90 is just one obsolete version. 2. Place your subroutines and functions into a module. 3. `real*8` and `real(kind=8)` are not the same (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201609190916207618015) 4. use some indentation, your code is very hard to read.

Comment: Actually, your functions returns an array, it must be in a module, really. Or at least internal.

Comment: Actually, the function doesn't return an array, it returns a scalar (though it never sets a value for it so will probably return junk).  The argument `cube_root` is not the return variable for the function `cuberoot`.  It's a function with side effects !

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I see, but then I don't know why there is `real*8,dimension(1000)::cuberoot` in the main program.

Comment: sorry, I never used a module. so could you tell me how much the module will help in make correction to my function

Comment: The code's a pile of spaghetti written by someone who admits that she doesn't know Fortran.  I don't understand how people, even beginners, write such codes.  I suggest OP spends some time in documentation, perhaps starting with program structure, at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/2203/program-units-and-file-layout#t=201609191008061134613.

Comment: Mr. High Performance Mark, I hope you support more than fighting.

Answer (score 1):

Just a collection of the points immediately leading to the compiler reported errors. I am not saying that after fixing these the program will compile or run correctly.

1. `kind=8` and `*8` is not the same. You are lucky they give the same thing for the `real` type for this compiler, but they don't for the complex type. Please note that `complex*8` is single precision and `complex(kind=8)` is double precision in your compiler.

But also note that the `*8` notation for other types than `character` is not Fortran. It is not and has never been part of any Fortran standard.

2. In the main code you define the function `cuberoot` as

   ```
   real*8,dimension(1000)::cuberoot
   ```

First, your function does not return an array (but perhaps it should), so it is wrong. Second, array returning functions cannot be declared in this way anyway. Place your procedures into a module instead of declaring the type as above.

3. Your function `CUBEROOT` is wrong. It does not return anything. Perhaps you wanted something like

   ```
    FUNCTION CUBEROOT (XX)
      real(kind=something_better_than_8),dimension(1000) :: CUBEROOT
      real(kind=something_better_than_8), INTENT(IN),dimension(1000) :: XX

      cuberoot = EXP(LOG(XX)/3) !or just XX**(-1._something_better_than_8/3) if that is what you wanted
    END FUNCTION CUBEROOT
   ```

It MUST be placed in a module which contains `implicit none`.